# Using MapIndexed[List] on a dataset fails -- why?

Tags: operators, dataset

The following works:

```
MapIndexed[List]@{1, 2, 3}
(* {{1, {1}}, {2, {2}}, {3, {3}}} *)
```

This works too:

```
Dataset[{1, 2, 3}][MapIndexed[f]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Why does this not work?

```
Dataset[{1, 2, 3}][MapIndexed[List]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This works fine again:

```
Dataset[{1, 2, 3}][MapIndexed[{##} &]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This looks like a bug to me

Comment: Dataset[{1, 2, 3}][MapIndexed[List[##] &]]

Comment: This is very similar to the issue discussed in a [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56437/3066).

Comment: Similar to `Dataset[{True}][Apply[And]]`. I wonder if we are missing something

Answer (score 2):

Could it have something to do with `Dataset` type checking? The `Failure` object contains the following details.

> ```
> <|"MessageTemplate" :> Dataset::invalid, "MessageParameters" -> <|"Head" -> List,
>  "Arguments" -> {TypeSystem`Atom[Integer], TypeSystem`ZSignatures`PackagePrivate`i}|>|>
> ```

The problem does not occur if `MapIndexed[List]` is part of a composition:

```
Dataset[{1, 2, 3}][MapIndexed[List] /* f]
```

> f[{{1, {1}}, {2, {2}}, {3, {3}}}]

(It does not return a dataset presumably because the final form is not structured data. According to the `Dataset` documentation this means "a list or association or nested combinations of these".)

The `Failure` message does not seem to be from any operation that has failed, but instead seems to be from an extra check. Specifically,

```
Dataset[{1, 2, 3}][MapIndexed[List], FailureAction -> "Drop"]
```

returns a dataset with the expected entries:

[image]

Similarly,

```
 Dataset[{1, 2, 3}][MapIndexed[Inactive[List]]]
```

returns a result as expected:

[image]

Intriguingly (to me), the following works and returns a `Dataset`:

```
Dataset[{1, 2, 3}][MapIndexed[Inactive[List]] /* Activate]
```

The following also works:

```
Dataset[{1, 2, 3}][MapIndexed[List] /* Dataset]
```

I look forward to a more complete answer.